# Can I have file assets in my gluon mobile app that install into the app's file system?

Tags: gluon-mobile, gluonfx

I have used Gluon mobile to port a JavaFX app to iOS. Everything works great -- great tech stack!

I am now stuck on one last piece of my app. My app needs to have several files distributed with it.

I can't use resources for this purpose due to some limitations in a library I am using.

I need to somehow install some files in the iOS file system for my app, and then read those files from my app.

I have worked out how to get the root of the app's file system via:

```
Services.get(StorageService.class).
        flatMap(StorageService::getPrivateStorage)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> 
             new RuntimeException("Error retrieving private storage"));
```

That seems to work well.

What I am wondering is -- using the gluon-mobile toolchain can I bundle the files with my app somehow, and have them install with my app somewhere under the root of my app's file system so that I can access them from my app?

thx